# How do you pass the yes | command into a EOF inline shell for a non-bash shell

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, hashicorp-vault, amazon-cloudhsm

I am writing an automation script to download the aws cloud-hsm client and pcks for doing a aws-cloudhsm-client init-container for a vault enterprise deployment.

The goal is to automate the config and setup of the HSM integration for vault to reference.

This is a guide that details how to do it.

https://github.com/jacobmammoliti/aws-vault-cloudhsm

My issue is that the cloud-hsm cli provided with the cloud-hsm client doesn't have a auto yes feature for when you execute the change password command. In order to automate this I have it in a EOF block for inline script execution to use the cloud-hsm cli inside of my start up script to configure it.

The issue is I'm trying to use `yes |` to answer the prompt but I don't think the EOF inline script method supports that and I am trying to find another way around it because the cloud-hsm cli doesn't support it which is kinda silly.

Here is a test bash script I'm running from a ubuntu:18.04 shell inside of my Kubernetes cluster to workout the automation. The HSM is on a private network so I'm using a pod to be inside the HSM network.

```sh
apt update -y

apt-get install wget -y

wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -ab
export PATH=~/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}

python --version

wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudhsmv2-software/CloudHsmClient/Bionic/cloudhsm-client_latest_u18.04_amd64.deb

wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudhsmv2-software/CloudHsmClient/Bionic/cloudhsm-client-pkcs11_latest_u18.04_amd64.deb

apt install -y ./cloudhsm-client_latest_u18.04_amd64.deb

apt install -y ./cloudhsm-client-pkcs11_latest_u18.04_amd64.deb

export CLOUD_HSM_IP='HSM_IP'
export CUSTOMER_CA="base64encodedca"
export VAULT_DEFAULT_ADMIN_PASSWORD='password'
export VAULT_HSM_ADMIN_PASSWORD='myadminpassword'
export VAULT_USER='vault'
export VAULT_HSM_PASSWORD='myadminpassword'

echo "Configure Cloud HSM $CLOUD_HSM_IP"
/opt/cloudhsm/bin/configure -a ${CLOUD_HSM_IP}

echo "Config File"
cat /opt/cloudhsm/etc/cloudhsm_mgmt_util.cfg

echo "Echo Customer CA"
echo "${CUSTOMER_CA}" | base64 --decode > /opt/cloudhsm/etc/customerCA.crt

echo "Cat Customer CA"
cat /opt/cloudhsm/etc/customerCA.crt

echo "Execute cloudhsm cli"

echo "
yes | /opt/cloudhsm/bin/cloudhsm_mgmt_util /opt/cloudhsm/etc/cloudhsm_mgmt_util.cfg <<'EOF'
enable_e2e
loginHSM PRECO admin ${VAULT_DEFAULT_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
changePswd PRECO admin ${VAULT_HSM_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
logoutHSM
loginHSM CO admin ${VAULT_HSM_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
createUser CU ${VAULT_USER} ${VAULT_HSM_PASSWORD}
logoutHSM
quit
EOF
" > configure_hsm

cat configure_hsm

yes | bash configure_hsm

service cloudhsm-client start
```

Question:

How can I get around this issue because `yes |` doesn't work because cloud-hsm is its own cli?

Comment: Just `echo` will print an empty line, but printing empty lines is generally just making your script harder to use. Anyway, the actual code you post should not contain such distractions; please review the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: @GranzZukel: _I **don't think** the EOF inline script method supports that_ : With this information, we can't help you at all. If you want to remote control another application, you first need to find out **how** it aquires its input. While we would expect that a well-behaved application should process standard input, or at least provide a way to make it use standard input, we can't force every programmer to write his applications in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of which shell you are using, a subprocess can only receive standard input from one place.

Anything which looks like

```sh
something | binary <<eof
...
eof
```

is basically an ambiguous redirect. Should `binary` receive standard input from the pipe, or from the here document? It can't be reading both.

(Quick testing on Bash and Alpine Linux indicates that these shells prefer the here document in this situation, and ignore the pipe. I'm too lazy to check if this is defined somewhere like POSIX.)

From a brief read of [the documentation](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cloudhsm-user-guide/blob/master/doc_source/cloudhsm_mgmt_util-createUser.md) I'm guessing you want to respond `y` to the "are you sure?" prompts after several of these commands. Just add that in the here document just like all the other input.

```sh
/opt/cloudhsm/bin/cloudhsm_mgmt_util /opt/cloudhsm/etc/cloudhsm_mgmt_util.cfg <<'EOF'
enable_e2e
loginHSM PRECO admin ${VAULT_DEFAULT_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
changePswd PRECO admin ${VAULT_HSM_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
y
logoutHSM
loginHSM CO admin ${VAULT_HSM_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
createUser CU ${VAULT_USER} ${VAULT_HSM_PASSWORD}
y
logoutHSM
quit
EOF
```

For what it's worth, quoting the `'EOF'` marker will prevent the shell from expanding the variables in the here document; I'm guessing probably you would not want that?